# Android live wallpaper draw in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, drawing

I'm developing a live wallpaper with multitouch support.
For each finger on the screen it draws a small bitmap on a big bitmap.

The wallpaper is ready now, but when you touch it with two or more fingers, the wallpaper is getting slower, and also the launcher.

Is it possible to draw the wallpaper in a separate thread or to prevent slowing down the launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm drawing the wallpaper with OpenGL ES 2.0 and a custom fragment shader, this is faster